# SQL Server Timetable query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query and data that I need to generate a timetable from.

My current query is below:

```
SELECT contract.lect_code code1,
       contract.coll_code code2,
       line_date,
       start_time,
       end_time,
       DATEPART(DW,line_date) AS day_number,
       datename (dw,line_date) AS nameofday,
       convert(varchar(8),start_time,108) AS start_time2,
       convert(varchar(8),end_time,108) AS end_time2
FROM bk_line
INNER JOIN contract ON contract.contract_no = bk_line.contract_no
WHERE line_date BETWEEN '2013/09/23' AND '2013/09/27'
  AND coll_code = 'TEL01'
  AND bk_line_status = 'CE'
--And lect_code = 10430973
```

This gives me data in the following format :[image]

I need a way of breaking down the times into 15 minutes slots for each code1 and line date.

Something like this:

`code1 | code2 | line_date | 0900worked | 0915worked | 0930worked |`

where the values in `0900worked` would be `T` or `F`.

--

**EDIT**

I need to group the periods by code1 and line_date. Therefore in the example above, `1045096` worked two sessions on `2013/09/25`. I need both sessions to appear on the same line with all periods calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  case
        when convert(varchar(8),end_time,108) >= '09:15:00'
             and convert(varchar(8),start_time,108) <= '09:00:00' 
             then 'T'
             else 'F'
        end as [0900worked]
,       case
        when convert(varchar(8),end_time,108) >= '09:30:00'
             and convert(varchar(8),start_time,108) <= '09:15:00' 
             then 'T'
             else 'F'
        end as [0915worked]
,       ...
```

Comment: +1 spot on...could be a big query if against ten intervals ...but suppose that is the nature of the beast

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added it to my code and it works fine. I have another issue. I'll post it as an edit.

Comment: You can enclose the case in `max(case ... end) as [0900worked]`.  Because `'T' > 'F'`, that would return true if any row in the group included the 9:00-9:15 interval.

Comment: Thanks. I put the above in a CTE then used max for each of the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way, but I think there are better ways to check if someone worked in a given interval!

```
with "nums"
as
(
  select 1 as "value"
  union all select "value" + 15 as "value"
  from "nums"
  where "value" <= 95*15
)
, "intervals"
as
(
  select
  "id" = "value" / 15
  , "startDate" =  dateadd( minute, "value" -1 , dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()), 0))
  , "endDate" =  dateadd( minute, "value" + 14, dateadd( year, datediff( year, 0, getdate()), 0 ))

from
  "nums"
)
,"matched"
as
(
select 
    I.*
    , D."id" as "code1" 
from 
    intervals as I
left join "data" as D
    on D."startDate" <= I."startDate"
    and D."endDate" >= I."endDate"
)   
select
*
from
(
  select
    "code1"
    , "startDate"
  from
    "matched"
) as Data
  pivot( count(Data."startdate") 
  for "startDate" 
  in (  "2013-01-01 00:00:00.000"
      , "2013-01-01 00:15:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 00:30:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 00:45:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 01:00:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 01:15:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 01:30:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 01:45:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 02:00:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 02:15:00.000" 
      , "2013-01-01 02:30:00.000" 
     )) as p
where p.code1 is not null
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9e76/1/0)

Comment: Query gives 0 and 1 instead of T and F, but you could easily put a `case when` around it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an intervals table using something like this:

```
;with t as
 (
 select cast('00:00:00' as time) as intStart,
 0 as l
 union all
 select DATEADD(MINUTE, 15,intStart),
 l+1
 from t
 where intStart<='23:30:00'
 )
select * 
from t;
```

Then you can use this to join onto your data and gives scope to look at any of  the 15mins intervals during the day.

You can then use Andomar's select statement against any of the intervals.